# GCC error installing lxml with pip on Mac OSX with Xcode

Tags: python, xcode, macos, lxml

I'm a noob trying to install lxml into an 2.7.3 installation of Python on my Mac.

I managed to install it into the Apple distribution but `pip install lxml` to that version returns the error:

error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1

Having scouted around on Stackoverflow the consensus is that there isn't Xcode, but it's definitely in place.

Can anyone help? Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Did you install the command line tools? See also http://holgr.com/blog/2012/02/xcode-4-3-and-homebrew-where-did-my-command-line-tools-go/

Comment: Have you tried: pip install lxml

Comment: Yes, that's what gave me the error.

Comment: I did, but I've noticed that I need to upgrade them after updating Xcode to the latest version a couple of days ago. I'll have another go after that's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lxml package has to be compiled on your system (using llvm-gcc-X.X which is the Mac OS X version of gcc) so in order to complete the installation of lxml you must have XCode installed and also the XCode command line tools (for install instructions look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html)).
Personally, I just finished installing Scrapy-0.14 and it compiled lxml in the same manner.
Good Luck.